# Duvida com conexão com banco de dados php com mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou aprendendo sobre php e mysql, vejo vários tutoriais na internet e uma duvida que me surgiu é, vejo que se criam várias variáveis e depois é colocando essas variáveis no comando, exemplo:

```
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$pass = "";
$dbname = "vendas";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $pass, $dbname);
```

Porque não coloca de vez no comando?? exemplo:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','vendas');
```

Qual objetivo de usar as variáveis neste caso ?

Comment: Basicamente ambas são escolhas pessoais. Na prática, nenhuma das maneiras é "melhor" ou "pior" que a outra, e funcionam da mesma maneira. Se você tem uma conexão só no começo do código, não atrapalha em nada colocar direto na função. Se você vai usar estes dados depois de outras partes lógicas do código, separar as variáveis no começo do código fica mais fácil de organizar. Agora, como no primeiro exemplo, em que a função de conexão está logo em seguida das variáveis, não faz muito sentido. Resumindo: dá na mesma, use o que for mais conveniente ou desejável para o seu caso concreto.

Comment: Entendi agora, igual vc comentou "como no primeiro exemplo, em que a função de conexão está logo em seguida das variáveis, não faz muito sentido", também para mim não fazia sentido nenhum. Mas se você for utilizar esses dados em outros lugares é melhor colocar em variáveis, valeu pela explicação.

Comment: acabei postando como resposta pra poder complementar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente ambas são escolhas pessoais. Na prática, nenhuma das maneiras é "melhor" ou "pior" que a outra, e funcionam da mesma maneira.

Se você tem uma conexão só no começo do código, não atrapalha em nada colocar direto na função. Se você vai usar estes dados depois de outras partes lógicas do código, deixar os dados em variáveis no começo do código torna mais fácil a manutenção.

Agora, como no primeiro exemplo, em que a função de conexão está logo em seguida das variáveis, não faz muito sentido. Resumindo: dá na mesma, use o que for mais conveniente ou desejável para o seu caso concreto.

Não faz parte da pergunta, mas acho bom comentar que mais importante que separar as variáveis, para fins de reaproveitamento, é ter a conexão num arquivo separado, por exemplo `dbconnect.php` que faça a conexão para você, e nas páginas todas que usem o DB você use `require_once( 'dbconnect.php' );`, assim só terá um lugar para ajustar no caso de uma mudança de servidor ou configuração em geral.

<sub>Nota: em princípio a pergunta aparenta ser uma que gera respostas "baseadas em opinião", o que normalmente é motivo para fechamento, mas como se trata de esclarecimento pra saber se há algum motivo, e não "qual é melhor", achei adequado responder</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Fica melhor para organização, e afins, para quando outra pessoa que não seja você consiga compreender mais facilmente. E quando você transfere para um servidor on line, você não precisa ficar procurando onde você conectou com o banco, você só troca o valor das variáveis. São boas práticas de organização e reutilização do código.
Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Meu querido, citar `"e tal"` pode significar muita coisa que precisa ser explicada ou pode significar absolutamente nada. No caso caso, `"e tal"` significa o que ?

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário, editei e escrevi de uma maneira de melhor compreendimento.